# How to manage split APK's?

Tags: c#, android, apk, adb

I'm making a Windows program to extract, store and install APK files from and to devices. It uses ADB as the only way to connect to the device. It gets APK's info via aapt and organizes them in a folder structure (%userprofile%\Documents\AndroidToolbox\repo\PACKAGENAME\SDKVERSION\SUPPORTEDARCHITECTURES.apk).
My problem is that Google implemented the App Bundle format, which divides packages into different APK and then installs appropriate files depending on target device specs.

An example: Chromecast app has 4 different files

`base.apk (the app code itself)`
`split_config.arm64_v8a.apk (for ARM 64 bit architecture)`
`split_config.es.apk (for spanish language)`
`split_config.xxhdpi.apk (for specific device density)`

...

But Netflix app has other split APKs:

`base.apk (the app code itself)`
`split_config.arm64_v8a.apk (for ARM 64-bit architecture)`
`split_config.es.apk (for Spanish language)`
`split_config.xxhdpi.apk (for specific device density)`
`split_voip.apk (Voice Over IP? Does Netflix has this feature?)`
`split_voip.config.arm64_v8a.apk (Voice Over IP for ARM 64-bit architecture?)`

How should I manage these files? How do I know which ones are indispensable? Are those unknown APKs compatible with every device? Any suggestion or idea is greatly appreciated :)